# Do the different versions of the Flash suggest that both universes will coexist in DCEU?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, dc-extended-universe, the-flash

Since the speedsters on the CW series The Flash and in Batman vs. Superman are both named Barry Allen, what does their existence point to?

Multiverses already exist in the CW series and with the cameo of Flash in Batman vs. Superman, it is growing a little bit confusing...

Will both the iterations build up to the DCEU or will the CW version be dropped in the near future?

Comment: good question since Supergirl has established a connection to the film version of Superman (Man of Steel) but will crossover with CW Flash

Comment: Where was the conection between Supergirl and Man of Steel? I guess i missed something

Comment: I'll have to look it up, but they've already said that the Arrowverse is completely separate from the DCU in the movies. I'll try to find it.

Comment: DC/WB has openly stated that there are no connections between their TV and movie universes with the *possible* exception that they *might* be doing a *Man of Steel* prequel on TV

Comment: Pretty sure there was a reference in the Supergirl pilot - memory is leading me to think it related to the "S" symbol meaning 'hope' but I can't recall atm and don't have the chance to look it up further

Comment: @NKCampbell 1. I'm pretty sure that *Man of Steel* borrowed that idea from *Superman: Birthright*, and 2. in *Supergirl* Kara says it's her family motto, "Stronger together."

Answer (score 9):

From a production standpoint, the movie and multiple television universes are entirely separate. You can see a graphical depiction of the current DC/WB landscape in [this objectively excellent blog post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/) on our amazing blog.

The man in charge of the DCEU, Zack Snyder, has repeatedly insisted that the TV universes will be separate from the movie ones:

> The director went on to add, "...I think that's sort of the thing I've embraced, and as opposed to trying to shoehorn all of these storylines into a single universe, we let the characters exist in multi-universe, and therefore it's a lot more fun and a lot more value for the audience. They get to see their favourite and most beloved characters on different adventures at the same time in different universes and it really makes the meal a lot richer and a lot more fun. We get to go with these guys in all different directions and that's really the joy of what we're trying to do over here at DC." [src](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/shows-like-flash-arrow-existing-separate-universe-dc-films-amazing-says-zack-snyder-1542558)

The fact that the Arrowverse already has a multiverse of it's own isn't going to impact the movie universe. If you want, I supposed you could consider the DCEU just one of the numerous universes in the multiverse, but it's one that the CW Flash will never<sup>1</sup> visit.

So far, this has resulted in a handful of characters that exist in more than one universe, played by different people with entirely different backgrounds:

- Barry Allen is the biggest name so far -- Snyder addressed Grant Gustin's character specifically on the heels of *Batman v Superman*

> "Even if Grant Gustin is my favorite guy in the world and he’s very good, we made a commitment to the multi-verse [idea], so it’s just not a thing that’s possible." [src](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/snyder-considered-grant-gustin-flash-article-1.2572225)

- The Suicide Squad has appeared multiple times on *Arrow*, including Deadshot and Amanda Waller. Both of those characters were killed off prior to the *Suicide Squad* movie, where they've all been recast. (There was also a very brief Harley Quinn Easter Egg-style cameo, but the TV guys were quickly told she was off limits as well.)
- Katana -- who was Masao's wife and Oliver Queen's friend on *Arrow*, is going to be a part of the Suicide Squad in the upcoming movie.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Until DC/WB changes their mind.</sub>

Comment: Exactly since Deadshot and Amanda Waller were killed in the Arrowverse and Deathstroke is no longer set to make a return, can we see Grant Gustin's FLASH death on the show?

Comment: you want to know, if the CW is going to kill off The Flash.. on *The Flash*.. ?

Comment: Since Wally West is already on the show and is a speedster in Comics, killing or vanishing of the Flash might be on the cards keeping in tandem with CW killing or getting rid of iterations of characters that coincide with DCEU...

Comment: I supposed they could have done that. They aren't. It's been explicitly stated, more than once by multiple DC/WB people, that TV Barry Allen and DCEU Barry Allen will continue to exist, as separate people, and have no relation to each other. They killed off Deadshot because he was a minor character on the show but Will Smith in the movies; they're not going to kill off the central character.

Comment: _"it really makes the meal a lot richer and a lot more fun"_ and a lot more confusing and exceedingly annoying

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, Snyder has mentioned the multi-verse in a recent interview.

He was explaining why Ezra Miller was cast as the Flash for *Batman v Superman* over Gustin. From [the NY Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/snyder-considered-grant-gustin-flash-article-1.2572225):

> “Even if Grant Gustin is my favorite guy in the world and he’s very good, we made a commitment to the multi-verse [idea], so it’s just not a thing that’s possible.”

Comment: Granted, this makes zero sense, as we've seen the multiverse with alternate versions of characters already. There's no reason why Barry from Earth-3 can't be some gritty badass, while Barry from Earth-1 is light-hearted.

Comment: Yes and Barry Allen being the exact same iteration of the Flash on 2 different earths is something that is not adding up!